# Should a space in a password count as a symbol when checking for complexity?

Tags: javascript, security, passwords

There is no doubt in my mind that spaces should be allowed in passwords. I see some websites disallow spaces and symbols in passwords and even enforce maximum length which seems totally nonsensical to me.

Normally I'd check that user passwords contain:

1. minimum of 6 characters
2. Upper case letters
3. Lower case letters
4. Numbers
5. Symbols

Here's my question:

**Which of these categories should space fall under? Can I count it as a symbol? Or is it in it's own category adding nothing but length to the perceived complexity of the password?**

Counting a space as a symbol would allow the following password:

`"Ab1   "`

Which frankly does not look safe so should I allow the spaces to count as symbols? (and do they add enough complexity to the password to be counted as symbols?)

This is the JavaScript function that I'd usually use to check passwords but given the above password this function will return false, deeming it insufficiently complex.

```
function checkPassword(password) {
    if (password.match(/[A-Z]/) 
      && password.match(/[a-z]/) 
      && password.match(/[0-9]/) 
      && password.match(/[£:#@~\.,|(etc....)]/) 
      && password.length >= 6) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }  
}
```

Comment: You know what's wrong with space? People may use it to write sentences as passwords. With other conditions this is actually the easiest way to generate a password. Plus it is easier to add a space at the end/begining (inside?) by mistake then any other character (happens everywhere all the time). Personally I would not allow it.

Comment: @freakish I'd encourage pass-phrases especially over 16 characters I'd bet a 16 character pass-phrase of only lower case and spaces will be harder to crack than a six character one containing letters of both cases, numbers and symbols. I'll agree that leading and trailing spaces are an issue and I've seen people trim them off but I'm not so sure that's a good idea. If it was me and I wanted a password ending in a space and I discovered it had automatically been trimmed, I'd be upset.

Comment: Possibly better fit for [security.se].

Comment: @nettux443 I'm thinking about sentences vs sets of random characters. Generally short password is easier to crack then the long one - you are right. But long real-life sentence is easier to crack then short random string. And normal people (i.e. not coders) tend to use real words as passwords. Of course you can't force them to generate random passwords. However you should not encourage them (by giving them spaces) to generate sentences. That's my opinion at least.

Comment: @freakish I'd still say that there is a place for *pass-sentences* eg I'd favor  something like *"nettux443 was here but not anymore"* over something like *"x!e£G9"* and I'd wager that the latter is still easier to crack due it's length

Comment: Why do you have to count the space in one of those categories? You do have the option not to count it.

Answer (score 0):

With calculating the strongness of a password, one tries to measure, how resistant a password will be against brute-force attacks. Actually this will ever be guesswork because it depends on the [methods](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hybrid_attack) an attacker uses for brute-forcing. Strong looking passwords can become trivial to crack, weak ones may resist, if the rules do not apply.

The password `Password-2015` will be accepted as strong password by most algorithms, though is in fact one of the weakest passwords possible. In my opinion only following tests make sense:

1. Test whether the entered password is part of existing dictionaries and reject them if they are.
2. Require a minimum length of the password.

If you still want to give feedback about the strongness of the users password, i would put the space character in the same category as other letters like "A" or "b". But this is only an opinion of course.